# Roman Numerals to Arabic (vinculum) - reading characters in a string

Tags: c++, c

I am currently working on a project that converts Roman Numerals to Arabic Numbers and vice versa.
I am also responsible to implement concepts like vinculum, where if you put a bar on top of a Roman numeral, the numbers below will be multiplied by 1,000.

The problem I am having is I can get only one side working, meaning:
I can either just convert from Roman Numeral to Arabic without Vinculum:
ex. I = 1, II = 2
However, when this works my vinculum code does not work.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
int romanToDecimal(char input[], size_t end) {

int roman = 0;

int vroman = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); ++i)
{
    int s1 = value(input[i]);
    int s2 = value(input[i]);

   if (input[i] == '-')
    {

        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j)
        {

            roman = (roman + value(input[j]));

        }

        roman *= 1000;



        for (int k = i + 1; k <= strlen(input); k++)
            roman += value(input[k]);

    }
    else
        roman += s1;
}

    return roman;

}
```

We use '-' instead of the bar on top of the characters, because we cannot do that in computer easily. So IV-, would be 4000 and XI- would be 11,000 etc...

I understand that the way I am doing the loop is causing some numbers that were converted to add twice, because if(input[i] == '-') cycles through each character in the string one at a time.

OK, so my question is basically what is the logic to get it to work? So if the string contains '-' it will multiply the number by 1000, if the string does not contain '-' at ALL, then it will just convert as normal. Right now I believe what is happening is that when `"if (input[i] == '-')"` is false, that part of the code still runs, how do I not get it to run at all when the string contains '-'??

Comment: By the time you've processed `IV` (assuming you've done it correctly), you should have `roman == 4`. Now if you encounter a dash, just set `roman *= 1000`. You don't need to look at the preceding characters again - you've already extracted all the information you need from them.

Comment: That said, your approach of processing characters one by one and simply adding up some "value" of each character can't possibly work - it can't distinguish `IV` from `VI`. The value of each character may depend on characters preceding or following.

Comment: You did well for a first time question here, but you really should read [ask] and [mcve], and pay more attention to properly formatting the code that you post.  Make use of the preview capabilities here, before you post your question.

Comment: Well I made a quick stab at fixing the formatting, but your code won't compile as it stands.  Always post an [mcve].

Comment: `k <= strlen(input)` will allow `k` to equal `strlen(input)`, and that could be bad. It's going to be in bounds thanks to the null terminator so it's not fatal, but probably won't give you the results you need.

Comment: `for (int k = i + 1; k <= strlen(input); k++)
            roman += value(input[k]);` eventually calls `value('\0');`.  J J why call `value()` on the _null character_?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am still trying to digest all of this and reading my prof's lecture notes. I forgot that C puts a \0 at the end of the character string, that was my bad. I still haven't implemented the code for IV or when preceding character is less than proceeding. I was just confused because if I put the *1000 in the loop it will multiple by 1000 as many as the loop runs. And I am not sure how to check whether a string contains a single character. I don't believe input[i] is the way because it only checks one character at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code seems incomplete or at least has some unused (like `end`, which if it represents the length of string could be used in place of the following repeated `strlen(input)`) or meaningless (like `s2`) variables.

I can't understand the logic behind your "Vinculum" implementation, but the simple

```
roman += s1;  // Where s1 = value(input[i]);
```

It's clearly not enough to parse a roman number, where the *relative position* of each symbol is important. Consider e.g. "IV", which is 4 (= 5 - 1), vs. "VI", which is 6 (= 5 + 1).

To parse the "subtractive" notation, you could store a partial result and compare the current digit to the previous one. Something like the [following](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8JS70pCYaUlgtYQO):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int value_of(char ch);

long decimal_from_roman(char const *str, size_t length)
{
    long number = 0, partial = 0;
    int value = 0, last_value = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == '-')
        {
            number += partial;
            number *= 1000;
            partial = 0;
            continue;
        }
        last_value = value;
        value = value_of(str[i]);
        if (value == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong format.\n");   
            return 0;
        }
        if (value > last_value)
        {
            partial = value - partial;
        }
        else if (value < last_value)
        {
            number += partial;
            partial = value;
        }
        else
        {
            partial += value;   
        }
    }   
    return number + partial;
}

int main(void)
{
    char const *tests[] = {
        "I", "L", "XXX", "VI", "IV", "XIV", "XXIII-",
        "MCM", "MCMXII", "CCXLVI", "DCCLXXXIX", "MMCDXXI", // 1900, 1912, 246, 789, 2421
        "CLX", "CCVII", "MIX", "MLXVI"                     // 160, 207, 1009, 1066 
    };
    int n_samples = sizeof(tests) / sizeof(*tests);

    for (int i = 0; i < n_samples; ++i)
    {
        long number = decimal_from_roman(tests[i], strlen(tests[i]));
        printf("%12ld %s\n", number, tests[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int value_of(char ch)
{
    switch (ch)
    {
        case 'I':
            return 1;
        case 'V':
            return 5;
        case 'X':
            return 10;
        case 'L':
            return 50;
        case 'C':
            return 100;
        case 'D':
            return 500;
        case 'M':
            return 1000;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Note that the previous code only checks for wrong characters, but doesn't discard strings like "MMMMMMMMMMIIIIIIIIIIIIIV". Consider it just a starting point and feel free to improve it.

Comment: Hi, I am still relatively new to CC.
May I ask what does the sizeof(tests)/sizeof(*tests) mean?
I am guessing that it gets the length of the tests[] array and the * is a pointer.
What does the pointer do in this case exactly? That's why in my code, I didn't really use it. But I know it is an important concept to understand for C programming.

Comment: @JJ `sizeof(tests)/sizeof(*tests)` gets the number of elements in an array. `sizeof(tests)` provides the size of `tests` in bytes. `sizeof(*tests)` provides  the size of the first value (and since they are all the same type, the size of any value) in `tests`in bytes. If you are compiling to the most recent C++ standards you can use the `std::size` function to compute the number of elements with a little less fuss. Note that due to [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) this will not work with an array passed into a function.

Comment: @JJ I posted a C program, despite your question beeing also tagged as C++, due to the snippet you posted. If you are primarly interested in C++, please edit the question to add that info. Back to your comment, yes, I used that pattern to "automatically" get the size of the array and no, you don't have to use it if you haven't alredy learned how pointers work. I could have explicitly used the size, (e.g. `const char *tests[16] = ...`) and then pass that number, but it must be correct (and updated if you decide to add another test) or add a NULL-terminator as a sentinel to stop the loop.